# Performance side effect with static internal Util classes?

Tags: java

For a util class that contains a bunch of static functionality that's related to the same component, but has different purposes, I like to use static internal classes to organize the functionality, like so:

```
class ComponentUtil {
    static class Layout {                    
        static int calculateX(/* ... */) {
            // ...
        }

        static int calculateY(/* ... */) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    static class Process {
        static int doThis(/* ... */) {
            // ...
        }

        static int doThat(/* ... */) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any performance degradation using these internal classes vs. just having all the functionality in the Util class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No : at compile time, a static internal class will be compiled as an external class file, having as name (in your example) `ComponentUtil$Layout`. Hopefully, references to this class will be resolved in the whole project. But it will be considered, at run time, like a totally independant class.

Comment: So, basically just the overhead of having the additional class, which I believe is only a few hundred bytes.  That should be okay for me. Thanks.

Comment: This class overhead only applies when these classes methods gets called : before the call of the first static method of your class, the class isn't even loaded in memory.

Comment: @Riduidel : Do you have a reference for the behaviour (beeing compiled as "external classes")

Comment: @Edward I guess it should be in the java compiler spec, as it is standardized behaviour.